# Algorithms for Sentiment Analysis on Entity

Tags: sentiment-analysis, named-entity-recognition

I want to make sentiment analysis for an entity which was found, like Google NLP.

Entity should have magnitude and score.

Please share with me the possible research papers.

p/s please not propose to make sentiment for sentence where the entity is located and them assign to entity from such sentence.

Answer (score 0):

A roll-your-own solution using Mathematica is described at https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/0245/c38fd1f3c7859c5e22382426178090faa395.pdf

I've not found such capability built into Mathematica's core, although that research paper is from 2013.

IBM Cloud's Text Analysis API also includes this capability: https://console.bluemix.net/apidocs/natural-language-understanding#entities

See also the responses to [sentiment analysis for multiple entry in one text](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/42220/sentiment-analysis-for-multiple-entry-in-one-text)

There may be others...

Comment: I already realized these ,using Claus linguistic structure