# Sentiment analysis for multiple entry in one text

Tags: deep-learning, rnn, word2vec, sentiment-analysis, nltk

I would like to do sentiment analysis on a set of financial news from the S&P 500 for given entities (organization names). However, each news (rows in my dataset) may have more than one entity and I have to do analysis for each entity separately the same news. First, my algorithm should find which entities are present in a specific news and then do sentiment analysis for them.

I would appreciate if someone could help me.

Example of output:

[image: example of output]

Comment: Partial overlap with https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/34199/algorithms-for-sentiment-analysis-on-entity/43489#43489

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Ensemble of "Target based sentiment" models worked for a similar use-case that I worked on.

Some of the models that were part of the solution :

1. http://sentic.net/sentic-lstm.pdf
2. https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01537896/document
3. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.05818.pdf